# How to change the order of tree view of the Category Entity

Tags: symfony

I am using the sonata tree view for the Category entity, and the order is displayed by id , I want to change the order and make it by another key like updateAt for example, and here is tree.html.twig used for this purpose, existed here:  vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/CRUD/tree.html.twig
and whether can I change it in the twig file or in the CategoryAdmin and how to do it.